# Is it possible that an object orbits another object without ever tangenting or crossing its equator?

Tags: orbital-motion

Imagine Object 1 beeing the earth and object 2 beeing the moon having a orbit around earth, like the yellow line is demonstrating.

[image]

Could something like this anyhow naturaly as standalone occur?
I'd say it couldn't but if I'm wrong: Could it stay stable?
And if nothing of both is true, would this be possible with the gravitation of a third object affecting object 2? Or would it then just transform into some other form of orbit?

Comment: How would you imagine this occurring with 3 or more objects?

Comment: @Feyre: No idea. My intuition says this wouldn't be possible but so I ask for backup, since just using intuition and then relying on it is no good concept, is it?

Comment: Well no, but I actually recently wrote a program which numerically solves any n-body problem,and was looking forward to testing some things out in case you did have something in mind.

Comment: If you have two objects only, they will both orbit about the system's center of mass, so your situation can't work.

Comment: @march: Note OP also considers a third body that might make this possible.

Comment: @Zaibis . Right! I should've said that the two body system can't work. I don't know about the n body system, but since stable orbits are rare, it seems difficult to realize.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work in a 2-body scenario.

In a 3-body scenario, yes, and this can even be shown from real world examples.

[Lagrangian orbits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) are reasonably well understood, where a 3rd body orbits a location defined by the masses and orbits of the first 2 bodies. the L4 and L5 locations follow or lead the 2nd body, but have stable orbits around them that do not go round the 2nd body.

Comment: Your wikipedia link looks to me as it would require the OP scenario to have a mass in the center of object2's yellow orbit circle. Did I get that wrong?

Comment: Of course - hence 3-body. The system as a whole is in orbit around the central body, but the local system can meet the OP's needs.